# Priming sugar/drop mixing worry, in a test bottling

Tags: bottle-conditioning, priming-sugar, timing

I'm preparing to bottle a 30 pint batch of Ginger Beer. It started at 1.041 and has finished at a steady 1.008 after 2 weeks or so.

I siphoned one bottle's worth earlier into a 500ml flip-top, and added one Coopers priming drop. After about 1 hour the drop had dissolved but I could see it sat in a sugary cloud at the bottom. Will it mix / convert naturally? It's at 18°C right now inside an empty tub incase it explodes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just leave it. The headspace is full of oxygen - even a gentle shake is enough to increase oxygen absorbtion into the beer. I would simply leave the beer standing as it is, which exposes the smallest surface area to oxygen. Oxygen uptake leads to sherry/cardboard flavours later, or just generally dulling of the beer flavor and faster staling.

The yeast will be distributed throughout the beer, or may settle to the bottom, depending upon if they were dormant when you racked the beer. Either way, with the sugar at the bottom, there is yeast where there is sugar and they will consume it - and there is always far more yeast than you need. During fermentation you have over a million yeast cells per ml of beer - for bottling you only need 10,000 cells/ml - a drop in cell density of 100 fold. Unless you filter, there is always more than this  present at bottling time.

So, no need to worry about it. Just drop in the coopers drop and leave for 2 weeks.

Answer (score 1):

It will eventually get to a state where the sugar is evenly distributed, but there's nothing stopping from you helping it get there. Gently turn the bottle upside down, then right-side up. Repeat a couple times.